# Problems with modifying the WordPress login page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So I'm working on my login page modification again... and I'm running into another issue. Here's the scenario... I've got a plugin that consists of two components: a script that rewrites the username field on the login/registration form, and a function that overrides the validation handler on registration.

Here are the files in question...

*validator.php*

```
<?php
// Rewrite registration form
function mpm_registration_form() {
    wp_enqueue_script('login_form', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/usernamerewrite.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action('login_head', 'mpm_registration_form');

// Register actions
add_action('register_post', 'mpm_validator_verify_account', 10, 3);

// Check username against minecraft.net database
function mpm_validator_verify_account($login, $email, $errors) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user='.rawurlencode($login));
    $mcacct = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($mcacct != 'true') {
        if($mcacct == 'false') {
            $errors->add('mc_error', __('<strong>Error:</strong> Minecraft account is invalid.'));
            return $errors;
        } else {
            $errors->add('mc_error', __('<strong>Error:</strong> Unable to contact minecraft.net.'));
            return $errors;
        }
        add_filter('registration_errors', 'mpm_validator_verify_account', 10, 3);
    }
}
```

*js/usernamerewrite.js*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /*global document: false */
    /*global $, jQuery */
    var username, reset;
    if ($('body').hasClass('login')) {
        username = document.createElement("input");
        username.type = 'text';
        username.name = 'log';
        username.id = 'user_login';
        username.className = 'input';
        username.size = '20';
        username.tabIndex = '10';
        reset = document.createElement("input");
        reset.type = 'text';
        reset.name = 'user_login';
        reset.id = 'user_login';
        reset.className = 'input';
        reset.size = '20';
        reset.tabIndex = '10';
        $('label').each(
            function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() === 'Username') {
                    $(this).html('Minecraft Username<br/>');
                    $(this).append(username);
                } else if ($(this).text().trim() === 'Username or E-mail:') {
                    $(this).html('Minecraft Username or E-mail:<br/>');
                    $(this).append(reset);
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I write the wp_enqueue_script line as it currently is (with the script being loaded in the header), the action function is handled properly but the rewrite never happens. Conversely, if I change it such that the script is loaded in the footer, the rewrite occurs, but the action is no longer handled properly (the username field is reset prior to being submitted). I'm at a complete loss.

Second (minor) annoyance: There is always a slight delay between the page loading and the occurrence of the rewrite. Any thoughts on how to make this more transparent would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If you're going to vote the question down, the least you could do is indicate why...

Comment: why are you creating new input elements in your js? Wp provides them no? As far as I understand, on the frontend you just want to replace some text saying 'minecraft username' instead of 'username' and on the backend you want to validate. Is that correct? In that case your js is doing to much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out! The way I was doing it was horrible... I really need to brush up on my JS/jQuery. Here's what I've ended up with which works beautifully in all my test cases, and also rewrites not just the field labels, but messages as well...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
'use strict';
/*global document: false */
/*global $, jQuery */
    $('label').each(
        function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Username', 'Minecraft Username'));
        }
    );
    $('.message').each(
        function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('username', 'Minecraft username'));
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Test also with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please just wrap your function in:

```
jQuery( document ).ready
(
   function( $ )
   {
        // your js here
   }
);
```

No need to put the (jQuery) behind your function.

If you run DOM modifications before the page has loaded, it can't work. You can now load it in the header and rest assured it will fire.

I don't quite see why the fields would be reset prior to submitting, since you don't bind to any submit event handler... If this still happens, let us know.

Instead of calling `if ($('body').hasClass('login'))` in your js you probably want to check in php (use the login_head action) if you are on the login page and not send this js to all the pages on your site. But get it working first before optimizing.

If the submission doesn't arrive on the backend, that's probably because your javascript recreates inputs with the same ID's than the wordpress inputs and thus replaces them. As far as I can tell that is not at all what you are after. Just replace the existing labels.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This actually did solve the issue of it not properly rewriting, but now the action doesn't work at all.

Comment: Also, given that there are ways to change the login url, what would you say is the better way of determining if the user is on the login page?

Comment: @Ghost1227 first things first. Did you do something like `error_log( print_r( $_POST, true ) );` to see if what you get back is exactly what you want? and also did the action fire at all or not? If you cant find the action firing, check $_POST at register_new_user() in wp-login.php. If that fails check it at admin-ajax.php and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: On detecting you login page, there is an action called 'login_head', which you could hook to in order to load your style only if you are on the login page.

Comment: login_head worked great! It actually handles the rewrite much smoother than the way I was doing it! So thanks for that... As for the other issue, adding the error_log line didn't return anything. When I submit the form, it clears the value in the username box and returns two errors: 'ERROR: Please enter a username.' and 'ERROR: Minecraft account is invalid.'. I'm still at a complete loss as to why the username field is being cleared.

Comment: @Ghost1227 I'm sorry, I just discovered that the post is not ajax. It goes to wp-login.php. Can you put the error_log there. You need to look in your php error log in order to see the result...

Comment: Putting it in wp-login.php does return the proper information... And yet the username field is still being cleared and returning an error as if the username is not being passed.

Comment: does that include in register_new_user()?

Comment: Yes. It always passes the correct info, but always clears and returns an error anyway.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I have update the sources in the original post. Also... If I remove the rewrite completely and fall back on just the action, it works fine.

Comment: What I still don't understand is why you create extra input fields. As far as I understand you just want to change the labels... By giving them the same id as the wp fields you probably replace them... and so they fire empty

Comment: If you take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11835731/664990), I did finally figure that out :P